# matplotlib interactive backend and remote server

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, matplotlib, remote-server

I have various python codes that generate figures with matplotlib. I need to be able to see these figures when I run the code on my laptop (so with an interactive matplotlib backend if I understood well), but I also need to be able to generate these figures on a remote server with minimal (ideally none) changes in my code (to be clear, I don't want the plots on the remote server to be displayed on my computer and I don't care whether they are displayed on the remote server, I just want the figures to be generated).

My laptop is a Mac OS X El Capitan version 10.11.6, I'm using python 3 with matplotlib 2.1.2, and the default matplotlib backend used on my machine is Qt5Agg.

The way I tried to do that is by switching to the 'agg' matplotlib backend before I put my codes on the remote server (with plt.switch_backend('agg')). However, when I do so, there are many differences in the figures that are generated on the remote server and on my local computer, for instance for the 'fontsize' option and with subplots (I guess because it's a different backend then on my laptop?). I would need a way to be sure the figures generated are the same, but as the 'agg' backend is non-interactive, I cannot use it on my laptop.

How can I do so? Should I try to use the same backend on both my laptop and remote server or is it not possible?
If someone can tell me at least what I should try to do, it would be really appreciated as I don't know what to look for by now =)

If other infos could be helpful just let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: There should not be any differences due to the backend, at least not between Agg and Qt5Agg (they are both agg!). So the actual problem you face may be independent on the backend, but since we do not know what the problem *is*, it's hard to help. Mind that questions about undesired behaviour without [mcve] are in general not useful.

Comment: I know this pain. IIRC, you can solve this issue to a large extend by setting the figure size explicitly upon initialization. Don't cite me on this (as it has been a while), but the apparent font size will depend on the figure size. The default figure size will depend on your display size, unless you never open the figure (which you wouldn't with Agg), in which case it uses some hard coded values. Hence the difference between server and local machine.

Comment: Also, it's not always possible to switch the backend after having loaded matplotlib.pyplot (at least that used to be the case). Hence I would advise having different matplotlibrc files for you local machine and the server, and set the backend there.

Comment: Finally (and this is more of a workflow recommendation), I personally let my servers do the heavy computational lifting and then save out the results in pickle, npy, or npz files. I then load the data in my local machine for plotting. You can't get any layout differences for local and remote computations if you use the same machine to draw the results. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the explanations and advises, and sorry about the 'broad question', actually I was not even sure myself what the problem actually was :) but thx, I'll be able to figure out a solution now!